# Navigating in an nXML buffer

Tags: navigation, nxml, xml

I'm editing an XML with nXML-mode. The file represents a document and has internal links of the form:

```
Follow <linktag docref="foo">this link</linktag> to
see <anchortag docref="foo">this text</anchortag>.
```

where linktag is one of `toc1, toc2, toc 3, a`, and anchortag is one of `document, page` (possibly others, I'd need to check).

What would be a good way to navigate between back and forth between an anchored text and the various links that point to it ?

Comment: What's this XML grammar? IMHO this looks a little too specific to work with common packages. This feature would probably belong to an emacs minor mode dedicated to your XML grammar. Does such a mode exist?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. This is internal grammar. I doubt there is any existing Emacs support for it specifically. I hoped that internal links were common enough for a generic solution to exist. I'll also welcome hints to write a solution specific to this problem. I could easily write one based on e.g. occur but that doesn't feel right.